# Files to Start With When Using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, directory

When I download the Bootstrap files, I'm getting the css, fonts, and js folders. The css folder contains the documents:

```
-bootstrap.css
-bootstrap.css.map
-bootstrap.min.css
-bootstrap-theme.css
-bootstrap-theme.css.map
-bootstrap-theme.min.css
```

Whenever I'm watching tutorials, people are using another styles.css sheet. Is this their own stylesheet that they started with, or am I missing a downloadable css sheet? When I look at the bootstrap.css file, I can never find what the instructor is looking at. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I strongly recommend looking at the documentation, specifically http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template to see exactly what you need to get started.

Comment: Any file that is not prefixed with bootstrap will most likely be own style sheets unless people have renamed the bootstrap files. For any information about getting started I also would like to recommend you the link that @Snappawapa proveded in his comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided files containing the base of bootstrap and making everything work out of the box.

For your own styling, it's recommended to use an separate css file, for example style.css.

You need to create this file by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [**gettings started**](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn) page. As you can see, they use `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.js` files, also `bootstrap-theme.min.css` designated as optional.

Good luck with BS and have fun.